# foreach loop is not working in mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
foreach (int workFlowServiceDetail in workFlowServiceDetails)
{
   using (var db = new AdminDb())
   {
      string workFlowServiceDtl = (from perm in db.WorkFlowPermission.AsNoTracking()
                                  where perm.WorkFlowPermissionId == workFlowServiceDetail
                                  select perm.Service).FirstOrDefault();
     //to select eligibility rules against this service
     string eligibility = (from definition in db.WorkFlowDefinition.AsNoTracking()
                          join model in db.WorkFlowModel.AsNoTracking()
                          on definition.WorkFlowDefinitionId equals model.WorkFlowDefinitionId
                          join permission in db.WorkFlowPermission.AsNoTracking()
                          on model.WorkFlowDefinitionId equals permission.WorkFlowDefinitionId
                          where model.ControllerNameId.Equals(current_ControllerId) && permission.WorkFlowPermissionId == workFlowServiceDetail
                          select permission.EligibilityRule).FirstOrDefault();

     if (eligibility == null)
     {
         string validationMessage = "";
         validationMessage = "Please set eligibility for workflow permission";
         serviceName = null;
         permissionId = 0;
         return new CustomBusinessServices() { strMessage = validationMessage };
     }

     string[] strTxt = workFlowServiceDtl.Split(';'); //split the service name by ';' and strore it in an array
     string serviceUrl = string.Empty;
     string workFlowServiceName = string.Empty;
     string classpath = string.Empty;
     workFlowServiceName = strTxt[0].ToString();
     workFlowServiceName = workFlowServiceName.Replace(" ", "");//get the service name by removing empty blank space for the word
     classpath = strTxt[1].ToString();

     //Invoke REST based service (like Node.Js service)
     if (strTxt.Length == 4)
     {
         serviceUrl = strTxt[3].ToString();
     }

     //Invoke c# based service
     else
     {
         serviceUrl = string.Empty;
     }

     var userLists = PermissionCallMethod(classpath, workFlowServiceName, new[] { workFlowImplemented, eligibility }, serviceUrl);

     /*****************************************Problem in this loop**********/
     if (userLists.UserList.Contains(userId))
     {
          serviceName = strTxt[0].ToString() + ";Aspir.Pan.Common.WorkFlowNotificationServices;" + strTxt[2].ToString();
          permissionId = workFlowServiceDetail;
          return userLists;
     }
   }
}
serviceName = string.Empty;
permissionId = 0;
return null;
```

Inside this loop a condition is checked to find a particular user form alist of user.Once the condition is true it jump out of the loop without checking the next one.

```
   if (userLists.UserList.Contains(userId))
   {
       serviceName = strTxt[0].ToString() + ";Asire.Pan.Common.WorkFlowNotificationServices;" + strTxt[2].ToString();
       permissionId = workFlowServiceDetail;
       return userLists;
   }
```

this is mainly because of the " return userList". so how can i make the loop run again. or please suggest some way to make it work.Is it possible to copy that returning userList to some List and return it after the loop.If so how can i write i list there. Please help me..?

Comment: where you initialize "userId" variable ?

Comment: just above the foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remove return in Foreach loop**

```
 var userListsTemp=null;
foreach (int workFlowServiceDetail in workFlowServiceDetails)
{
   using (var db = new AdminDb())
   {
      string workFlowServiceDtl = (from perm in db.WorkFlowPermission.AsNoTracking()
                                  where perm.WorkFlowPermissionId == workFlowServiceDetail
                                  select perm.Service).FirstOrDefault();
     //to select eligibility rules against this service
     string eligibility = (from definition in db.WorkFlowDefinition.AsNoTracking()
                          join model in db.WorkFlowModel.AsNoTracking()
                          on definition.WorkFlowDefinitionId equals model.WorkFlowDefinitionId
                          join permission in db.WorkFlowPermission.AsNoTracking()
                          on model.WorkFlowDefinitionId equals permission.WorkFlowDefinitionId
                          where model.ControllerNameId.Equals(current_ControllerId) && permission.WorkFlowPermissionId == workFlowServiceDetail
                          select permission.EligibilityRule).FirstOrDefault();

     if (eligibility == null)
     {
         string validationMessage = "";
         validationMessage = "Please set eligibility for workflow permission";
         serviceName = null;
         permissionId = 0;
         return new CustomBusinessServices() { strMessage = validationMessage };
     }

     string[] strTxt = workFlowServiceDtl.Split(';'); //split the service name by ';' and strore it in an array
     string serviceUrl = string.Empty;
     string workFlowServiceName = string.Empty;
     string classpath = string.Empty;
     workFlowServiceName = strTxt[0].ToString();
     workFlowServiceName = workFlowServiceName.Replace(" ", "");//get the service name by removing empty blank space for the word
     classpath = strTxt[1].ToString();

     //Invoke REST based service (like Node.Js service)
     if (strTxt.Length == 4)
     {
         serviceUrl = strTxt[3].ToString();
     }

     //Invoke c# based service
     else
     {
         serviceUrl = string.Empty;
     }

     var userLists = PermissionCallMethod(classpath, workFlowServiceName, new[] { workFlowImplemented, eligibility }, serviceUrl);

     /*****************************************Problem in this loop**********/
     if (userLists.UserList.Contains(userId))
     {
          serviceName = strTxt[0].ToString() + ";Aspir.Pan.Common.WorkFlowNotificationServices;" + strTxt[2].ToString();
          permissionId = workFlowServiceDetail;

          //return userLists;
          if(userListsTemp==null)
          {
              userListsTemp=userLists;
          }
          else
          {
              userListsTemp.Concat(userLists).ToList(); 
          }    
      }
   }
}
serviceName = string.Empty;
permissionId = 0;
return null;
```

Comment: it shows an error :Cannot assign <null> to an implicitly-typed local variable   var userLists=null;

Comment: What is the return type of  "PermissionCallMethod "??